# Java criteria for setting and getting

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am setting up criteria for database calls and am having trouble getting understanding how to set up my code.  I have put my criteria in and now need to know how I make sure I populate the variables right.  This is what I have.

```
Public class Key extends abstractDAO<key>{
Public List<Key> getKeyValues(){
Criteria c = createCriteria();
c.add(Restrictions.lt("id", 3)).addOrder(Order.asc("id")).list();
return c.list();
```

Now the table has 2 rows.  One is current and the second is a new request row.  The database has 3 columns.  Column 1 is the I'd,  column two is the key,  and 3 is a timestamp.  I need to populate all the variables in order.  I am not sure how to go about this in my key.java file

Key.java

```
@column(name="id")
private int actualID;

@column(name="key")
private Boolean actualKey;

@column (name="actualTime")
private Date actualTime;
```

Then repeats with requested,  requestKey,  and requestTime.  Then I have public get and sets for each.  Have not added any parameters to any method yet either. I am not sure how to set this file up so the list actually sets the variables when the DAO request the rows of the database.

Comment: Does this code work for you? What's the error you got?

Comment: It's attached to a huge system and I have not placed code in as I am not grasping how to make sure it sets the values in key.java

Comment: You are trying to populate the database or to retrieve values from it?
Also, you should post your mapped classes.

Comment: I will add the key.java that I wrote but I know as it stands now it will not do anything.  That's where I am stuck at.  Not sure how to set that file up.  I am retrieving from db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
public List<Key> getKeyValues()
{
    return createCriteria()
        .add( Restrictions.lt( "actualID", 3 ) )
        .addOrder( Order.asc( "actualID" ) )
        .list();
}
```

Provided that the rest of the mapping and the implementation of createCriteria() are correct, it should return a list of Key's objects whose ids are less than 3, ordered by id.

Comment: Okay and what I am confused on is how that populates the key. Java file correctly as row 1 and row 2 of database table are different

Comment: Hibernate maps database rows to java objects.

supposing you have a Key type annotated with @Table("BAR") and some fields annotated with @column(name = "FOO"), when you retrieve values from the database, hibernate will use java reflections and other "hacks" to create a Key object for each row in the table called BAR and sets its annotated fields with the values on the database.

Comment: If yout table have 2 rows whose ids are less than 3, then the list returned will contain 2 Key objects. Each one corresponding to one database row

Comment: I will post a picture of what I do have for  mapping

Comment: Okay I get a list of 2 objects.  I am not sure how to set that up in the key.java so they populate the variables correctly.  I can't have the data be scrambled.

Comment: The variable names are different for each row